# how to disable controls of master page used in content page while processing some event in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

The following code works fine for disabling content page controls, but how do I disable master page controls?

```
public void DisableControls(Control control,bool isEnable)
{
    if (control.HasControls())
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
        {
            DisableControls(c, isEnable);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (control is IPostBackDataHandler && !(control is IPostBackEventHandler))
        {
            if (control is WebControl)
            {
                ((WebControl)control).Enabled = isEnable;
            }
            else if (control is HtmlControl)
            {
                ((HtmlControl)control).Disabled = !isEnable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the effort to type that all out, but can't bothering to responses as answered?

Comment: @Pierreten, that's unneccessary. Give him chance to test and review the answers before you make those kind of comments.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - this person has been a member for 9 months and asked 21 questions.  I think that is plenty of time to test and review their answers.

Comment: My grammar was admittedly sloppy; but my point was that the question asker should really look into marking questions as being answered.  But Generic's right on these comments being noise; over and out.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable all the controls on a Master Page, just do the following:

```
DisableControls(this.Page.Master, isEnable);
```

Or, if you want to perform the method on a specific MasterPage contorl:

```
DisableControls(this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel1"), isEnable);
```

**Update:**

Why don't you just put a method on your MasterPage:

```
public void SetControlEnabledState(bool enabled)
{
   DisableControls(Menu1, enabled);
   DisableControls(Control2, enabled);
}
```

Then, to access it, just do the following from any page that uses the master page:

```
((MasterPageName)this.Page.Master).SetControlEnabledState(enabled);
```

Comment: @ush - Just saying 'not working fine' is not helpful. What's not working about it? What's the error? What code have you tried?

Comment: I have to disable menu control in master page
so i have used  

 //DisableControls(this.Page.Master.FindControl ("Menu1")  ,false  );//

Comment: Did you try if `this.Page.Master.FindControl ("Menu1")` returns correctly your control?

Comment: Well, the most often problem is that "Menu1" is not the correct id. Check the `Menu1.ClientID` in the master page. Also the ASP.Net 4.0 allows you to manage the ClientID. Other option for your problem is that the menu is not contained in the Master page directly, but in another control that child of MasterPage.

Comment: Thank You so much for all

the following code is working fine for me

             Menu mpLabel = (Menu)Master.FindControl("Menu1");
    
            ((WebControl)mpLabel).Enabled = false;

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to throw your custom event from your content page and then handle it in the master page. In this way make your master page independent from your content pages.